# Добавление данных в DataGrid в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Прошу помочь в следующем вопросе:
У меня есть метод, который делает десериализацию данных, после десериализации данные добавляются в список List, а после добавляются в DataGrid (поле actionGrid) в wpf.

```
 private void DeerializeObjectButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = 
                new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".dat";
            dlg.Filter = ".dat|*.dat*";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string fileName = dlg.FileName;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dlg.FileName))
            {
                var deserializeActions = Serializator.Deserialize
                    <List<Actions>>(dlg.FileName);
                actionList = deserializeActions;
                actionGrid.ItemsSource = actionList;
            }
        }
```

Но если в моем DataGrid уже были какие-то данные, то они соответственно все удаляются и обновляются согласно данным десериализации. 
Можно ли как-то добавить данные в конец списка, а не затирать их?
Я пробовал добавлять данные через

```
actionList.Add(new Actions()
                {
                    Date = ???,
                    Weight = ???,
                    Style = ???,
                    Distance = ???,
                    Speed = ???,
                    Kkal = ???
                });
```

Но это значит вместо вопросов нужно ставить deserializeActions, но но в нем никак не инициализировать отдельные поля, но и это кажется вновь создает новый лист и все равно затрет все данные. Можете подсказать есть ли способ добавить данные в конец DataGrid?

Comment: Научитесь использовать привязки! У вас должен быть класс, который будет установлен как `DataContext` текущего окна (`this.DataContext = new MyClass();`). Теперь в этом классе создаете публичное свойство коллекции (`public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items {get;set} = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>`). Далее в XAML вы пишете `<DataGrid ItemSource = "{Binding Items}" ... />`. Все, минимальная привязка у вас уже есть, все что добавится в привязанную коллекцию, будет отображено в UI. И теперь вы смело можете делать ваш `actionList.Add(new Actions()...`.

Comment: Что касается `никак не инициализировать отдельные поля` - то тут совершенно не понял, почему? Вообще по хорошему у вас должны быть класс Model, который будет отдавать методом все данные после десериализации. И класс ViewModel, который будет забирать у модели с помощью метода данные и на их основе заполнять показанную мною выше коллекцию.

Comment: Вам нужно создать временный List<Actions>. Сначала в него считать все item из DataGrid, потом в этот же лист добавить коллекцию deserializeActions. А потом привязать эту List<Actions> к DataGrid.